# Why is it that, when I try to shift all of the strings into my custom made Queue template and try to print, it only prints the last in the queue?

Tags: c++, queue

Truth be told, this is an assignment that I'm trying to complete. The basic thing that we have to do is create a Stack and Queue without STL and then create Stack and Queue with STL. I pretty much finished up creating my custom Stack, and it works perfectly. However, with Queue, whenever I try to shift strings into it and print it out, the console will only print out the string that was the last to be shifted. On top of that, whenever I try to unshift the last thing entered into the Queue with the code that I have, I end up getting a read access violation, that of which I am completely stumped on resolving.

If you don't mind, can you look through my code and help me understand what I did that is causing this error and the last entry in my Queue to be the only one printed out? Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    struct Node {
        //create a node struct
        string data;
        Node *next;
    };

    class Stack {
    public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack();
        void push(string a);
        string pop();
        string toString();
        bool isEmpty();
    private:
        Node * top;
    };

    class Queue {
    public: 
        Queue();
        ~Queue();
        void shift(string a);
        string unshift();
        string toString();
        bool isEmpty();
    private:
        Node * top;
        Node * bottom;
        int count;
    };

    Stack::Stack() {
        //initializes stack to be empty
        top = NULL;
    }
    Queue::Queue() {
        //initializes stack to be empty
        top = NULL;
    }

    Stack::~Stack() {
        //deconstructor to delete all of the dynamic variable 
        if (top == NULL) {
            cout << "Nothing to clean up" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Should be deleting..." << endl;
        }
    }
    Queue::~Queue() {
        //deconstructor to delete all of the dynamic variable 
        if (bottom == NULL) {
            cout << "Nothing to clean up" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Should be deleting..." << endl;
        }
    }

    void Stack::push(string a) {
        //Need a new node to store d in
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->data = a;
        temp->next = top;//point the new node's next to the old top of the stack

        top = temp;//point top to the new top of the stack
    }
    void Queue::shift(string a) {
        //Need a new node to store d in
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->data = a;
        temp->next = NULL;//point the new node's next to the old top of the stack
        if (isEmpty()) {
            top = temp;
        }
        else {
            top->next = temp;
            count++;
        }

        top = temp;//point top to the new top of the stack
    }

    string Stack::pop() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            string value = top->data;
            Node *oldtop = top;
            top = oldtop->next;
            delete oldtop;
            return value;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You can't pop from an empty stack!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    string Queue::unshift() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "You can't unshift an empty Queue!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            Node *oldbot = top;
        if (top == bottom) {
            top = NULL;
            bottom = NULL;
        }
        else {
            string value = top->data;
        }
            delete oldbot;
            count--;
        }
    }

    string Stack::toString() {
        string result = "top ->";
        if (isEmpty()) {
            result = result + "NULL";
            return result;
        }
        else {
            Node *current = top;
            while (current != NULL) {
                result = result + current->data + "->";
                current = current->next;
            }
            result = result + "(END)";
            return result;

        }
    }
    string Queue::toString() {
        string result = "top ->";
        if (isEmpty()) {
            result = result + "NULL";
            return result;
        }
        else {
            Node *current =top;
            while (current != NULL) {
                result = result + current->data + "->";
                current = current->next;
            }
            result = result + "(END)";
            return result;

        }
    }

    bool Stack::isEmpty() {
        return(top == NULL);
    }
    bool Queue::isEmpty() {
        return(top == NULL);
    }

int main()
{
    Stack *s = new Stack();
    cout << "Output when empty: " << endl << s->toString() << endl;
    s->push("Cheeseburger");
    s->push("Pizza");
    s->push("Large coffee");
    s->pop();
    cout << "Output when not empty: " << endl << s->toString() << endl;
    delete s;

    cin.get();

    Queue *b = new Queue();
    cout << "Output when empty: " << endl << b->toString() << endl;
    b->shift("Cheeseburger");
    b->shift("Pizza");
    b->shift("Large coffee");
    cout << "Output when not empty: " << endl << b->toString() << endl;
    b->unshift();
    delete b;
    cin.get();

}
```

Comment: `bottom` is always NULL, because you never set it.

Comment: BTW. This is a perfect way to learn to use debugger. It would allow you to inspect every variable during runtime and go step-by-step through your code.

Comment: In `Queue::shift`, you throw away all the current queue content by doing `temp->next=NULL;` and `top=temp;`. I would reccomend you to use pen and paper and draw what happes with all the pointers and nodes in `shift` and `unshift`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment below statement in Queue::shift method -

```
top = temp;
```